# Group json objects with keys by underscore js

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, underscore.js

I have JSON object as below, i am trying to group and push this object by first set of keys.

```
main =  {"answer_options":{
            "1":{"1":"optical projection<\/p>\r\n","2":"optical mechanism projection<\/p>\r\n","3":"mechanical projection<\/p>\r\n","4":"all the above<\/p>\r\n"},
            "2":{"5":"Greenwich to the place<\/p>\r\n","6":"equator to the poles<\/p>\r\n","7":"equator to the nearer pole<\/p>\r\n","8":"equator to the nearer pole along the meridian of the place<\/p>\r\n","9":"none of these.<\/p>\r\n"}},
    "question":
            {"1":"The stereo plotting instruments are generally manufactured on the principle of<\/p>\r\n","2":"Latitude of a place is the angular distance from<\/p>\r\n"}
    };
```

I trying to get the output as below.. Can any one help on this.

```
{"1" : 
        {{"1" : "The stereo plotting instruments are generally manufactured on the principle of<\/p>\r\n"},
        {"1":"optical projection<\/p>\r\n","2":"optical mechanism projection<\/p>\r\n","3":"mechanical projection<\/p>\r\n","4":"all the above<\/p>\r\n"}}, 
    {"2": 
        {{"2" : "Latitude of a place is the angular distance from<\/p>\r\n"},
        {"5":"Greenwich to the place<\/p>\r\n","6":"equator to the poles<\/p>\r\n","7":"equator to the nearer pole<\/p>\r\n","8":"equator to the nearer pole along the meridian of the place<\/p>\r\n","9":"none of these.<\/p>\r\n"}}
    }
```

Comment: lets see what you have done, so far

Comment: Yeah, the output should be in {}.

Comment: `{{` is not valid JSON. Everything inside `{}` must be `"key":value`

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `{"question": { "1": "The stereo..."}, "answer_options": {"1": "optical projection", "2": "optical mechanism", ...}}`

Comment: each question having key as unique id and answer option having this id as key (set of answer options for each question). I want to get this in a optimized format. If question id and answer set id same then push question and answer set in one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected out is not really a advisable (*or commonly used*) format. This is an *alternative* approach. You can use `for` / `in` to loop thru questions and match it to the corresponding answer options.

```js
main = {
  "answer_options": {
    "1": {
      "1": "optical projection<\/p>\r\n",
      "2": "optical mechanism projection<\/p>\r\n",
      "3": "mechanical projection<\/p>\r\n",
      "4": "all the above<\/p>\r\n"
    },
    "2": {
      "5": "Greenwich to the place<\/p>\r\n",
      "6": "equator to the poles<\/p>\r\n",
      "7": "equator to the nearer pole<\/p>\r\n",
      "8": "equator to the nearer pole along the meridian of the place<\/p>\r\n",
      "9": "none of these.<\/p>\r\n"
    }
  },
  "question": {
    "1": "The stereo plotting instruments are generally manufactured on the principle of<\/p>\r\n",
    "2": "Latitude of a place is the angular distance from<\/p>\r\n"
  }
};

var newMain = {};
for (var key in main.question) {
  newMain[ key ] = [
      main.question[key],
      main.answer_options[key]
    ];
}

console.log(newMain);
```

Comment: Yes, this what i am looking for.

Comment: Great! Happy to help @PrudhviMallavarapu